# Working with a big CSV file in MATLAB

Tags: mysql, matlab, file-io, csv, bigdata

I have to work with a big CSV file, up to 2GB. More specifically I have to upload all this data to the mySQL database, but before I have to make a few calculation on that, so I need to do all this thing in MATLAB (also my supervisor want to do in MATLAB because he familiar just with MATLAB :( ).

Any idea how can I handle these big files?

Comment: What kind of calculation? Does it need data from the full file or could you process it line by line?

Comment: A description of your file format would be most helpful.

Comment: @iUngi: All "CSV" means is that the values you have are delimited by commas, but that doesn't give much help. For example, you could have mixtures of strings, integers, floats, etc. and different numbers of these per line of the file. It appears you already got the answer you want (since you marked one as "accepted"), but in the future please keep in mind that you will be more likely to get good answers if you make your question as clear and detailed as you can.

Comment: Fortunately I don't have strings on the file, just integers or float, the first row is the name of the fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should probably use [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) to read the data in in chunks and then process. This will probably be more efficient than reading a single line at a time. For example, if you have 3 columns of data, you could do:

```
filename = 'fname.csv';
[fh, errMsg] = fopen( filename, 'rt' );
if fh == -1, error( 'couldn''t open file: %s: %s', filename, errMsg ); end
N  = 100; % read 100 rows at a time
while ~feof( fh )
  c  = textscan( fh, '%f %f %f', N, 'Delimiter', ',' );
  doStuff(c);
end
```

EDIT

These days (R2014b and later), it's easier and probably more efficient to use a [`datastore`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html).

Comment: +1. Could I talk you in to including more detail in the error message? IM(NS)HO verbose diagnostics make debugging way easier and are a good habit to expose example code readers to. `file = 'fname.csv'; [fh,errMsg] = fopen(file, 'rt'); if fh == -1; error('Couldn''t open file %s: %s', file, errMsg); end; ... fclose(fh);`

Answer (score 0):

There is good advice on handling large datasets in MATLAB in [this file exchange item](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9060).

> Specific topics include:
>   * Understanding the maximum size of an array and the workspace in MATLAB
>   * Using undocumented features to show you the available memory in MATLAB
>   * Setting the 3GB switch under Windows XP to get 1GB more memory for MATLAB
>   * Using textscan to read large text files and memory mapping feature to read large binary files