# large data file in matlab doesn't load/import

Tags: matlab, memory, bigdata

I have been trying to load data file (csv) into matlab 64 bit running on win7(64 bit) but get memory related errors. The file size is about 3 GB, containing date ( dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss) in first column and bid and ask prices in another two columns. The memory command returns the following :

```
  Maximum possible array:              19629 MB (2.058e+010 bytes) *
  Memory available for all arrays:     19629 MB (2.058e+010 bytes) *
  Memory used by MATLAB:                 522 MB (5.475e+008 bytes)
  Physical Memory (RAM):               16367 MB (1.716e+010 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

Can somebody here please explain if the max possible array size is 19.6 GB then why would matlab throw a memory error while importing a data array that is just about 3GB. Apologies if this is a simple question to the experienced as I have little experience in process/app memory management.

I would greatly  appreciate if someone would also suggest solution to being able to load this dataset into matlab workspace.

Thank you.

Comment: The data in your csv is converted to native data types. I do not know how you read the date, but numbers are 8 byte doubles. So depending on the numbers you have in your file, the memory consumption may be larger than the file size itself. You need to show more information, e.g. post part of the input file, and the code you use to read it. And the error messages.

Comment: Thank you . I just managed to load the data into matlab using the following function:   textscan(fileid,'%s %f %f','Delimiter',',');  the date field as string. You are right, as i watched the resource utilization , the entire 16GB ram was utilized for this. I need to learn about other formats that could be used for this. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in memory management but from experience I can tell you that you will run into all kinds of problems if you're importing/exporting 3GB text files.

I would either use an external tool to split your data before you read it or look into storing that data in another format that is more suited to large datasets. Personally, I have used `hdf5` in the past---this is designed for large sets of data and is also supported by `matlab`.

In the meantime, these links may help:

[Working with a big CSV file in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702872/working-with-a-big-csv-file-in-matlab?rq=1)

[Handling Large Data Sets Efficiently in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9060)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I managed to upload the data into matlab using textscan function. But all the 16GB ram was  utlized.Thank you for your suggestion on hdf5, I get the date from a vendor who would provide it in csv format -  is it possible to convert the file format to hdf5 directly before loading the data into matlab ?  Thank you .

Comment: It is possible, but you might need to write the tool to do so yourself. When I did it, I used python to read in CSV files and convert them to hdf5. Honestly, the simplest answer would be to ask your vendor to supply the data in a sensible format. Given that its all time-stamped data it would make sense---to me at least---to split the data into smaller chunks. Splitting csv files into smaller parts would also be considerably easier than converting to hdf5. In a unix environment you could split them directly using the `split` command for instance. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you - I will check the conversion . I agree it is best to ask the vendor to see if they can provide the data in more manageable format. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10655798/271811) showing how to use `memmapfile()` to read huge text files in matlab. This technique may help you as well.

Comment: Thank you . I will check the code to see how I can use it for my model. Thanks a lot.